# Improving load balancing in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following strings as the keys. From the below coding, I see the all the keys go to the same reducer, though there are many reducers. In the end, the same reducer is over loaded. I want, each key(String), to go to a different reducer. Pls help me with this issue. Thanks!

```
String a = "71 1 2";
String b = "72 1 1";
String c = "70 1 3";

int hash_a = a.hashCode();
int hash_b = b.hashCode();
int hash_c = c.hashCode();

int part_a = hash_a % 10;
int part_b = hash_b % 10;
int part_c = hash_c % 10;

System.out.println("hash a: "+hash_a+" part_a: "+part_a);
System.out.println("hash b: "+hash_b+" part_b: "+part_b);
System.out.println("hash c: "+hash_c+" part_c: "+part_c);

Output:

hash a: 1620857277 part_a: 7
hash b: 1621780797 part_b: 7
hash c: 1619933757 part_c: 7
```

Comment: Does using `new Text("71 1 2").hashCode()` give you any better results (sorry too lazy to fire up an IDE and check). `Text.hashCode()` uses the `WritableComparator.hashBytes(byte[])` method, and may give you a better answer

Comment: Ignore my last, looks like WritableComparator and String hashCode methods are comparable.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for the reply. I think that if they are comparable, we can use it for sorting, but still, they reach the same reduce. Am I correct?  Say, Sorting "71 1 2" and then comes "71 1 3", etc. But if the partition num returned by the partitioner is same(using modulus), then they still reach the same reducer. Am I correct? If that is the case, how does it solve the problem?

Comment: If they all results in the same modulo then yes it won't help. I guess you need to investigate @seedhead's answer

Answer (score 1):

One option is you define a custom [partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Partitioner.html) instead of using the default HashPartitioner to ensure that your keys are spread evenly across your reducers.

Comment: Can you tell me what logic to use in Custom partitioner?

Comment: If we consider the method: public int getPartition(K key, V value,
int numReduceTasks) {
return (key.hashCode() &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp; Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;}, we still nedd to use %(modulus operator) for getting the partition number, even if it's a custom partitioner. So still, if two keys though different still return the same partition num, they reach same reducer. Is there a way to make each key, reach a different reducer or atleast evenly spread. From my implementation, I see that some reducers are overloaded while some no load at all, inspite of having different keys.